# Using Python To Access E-mail (Lotus Notes)

Tags: python, api, lotus-notes, email-attachments

Basically, I need to write a Python script that can download all of the attachment files in an e-mail, and then organize them based on their name. I am new to using Python to interact with other applications, so I was wondering if you had any pointers regarding this, mainly how to create a link to Lotus Notes (API)?

Comment: There is no one way to "download all the attachment files in an e-mail", because there are a dozen different ways to talk to a mail server in the first place: IMAP, POP, MAPI, Exchange WebDAV, Lotus WebDAV, old-style Notes API, a variety of different Web RPC and REST mechanisms, accessing the Notes server as a database via ODBC, …

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in LotusScript as an export of data. This could be an agent that walks down a view in Notes, selects a document, document attachments could be put into a directory. Then with those objects in the directory(ies) you can run any script you like like a shell script or whatever.

With LotusScript you can grab out meta data or other meaningful text for your directory name. Detach the objects you want from richtext then move to the next document. The view that you travel down will effect the type of documents that you are working with.